Autoplay for YouTube video not working as background video on iPad/mobile devices
I am using YouTube video in the hero section of webpage,video play fine on iPhone, Desktop however its doesn't auto play on iPad.
I did add all the necessary attributes to it based on various tutorials. However it doesn't auto play
<div class="bg-video-wrapper"> 
    <iframe 
        allow="autoplay" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t-ZNZYCB39s?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&mute=1&playsinline=1&background=1" 
        frameborder="0" 
        webkitallowfullscreen 
        mozallowfullscreen 
        allowfullscreen 
        playsinline
        allow="autoplay; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture">
    </iframe>
</div>

Is there an working solution or iOS doesn't allow autoplay of YouTube videos.
I tried with YouTube API, even that doesn't seem to work


var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // 2. Create a <div> (player) and create a player variable.
        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                videoId: '-VmL6-zpgx8', // YouTube Video ID
                playerVars: {
                    'autoplay': 1,
                    'loop': 1,
                    'playlist': '-VmL6-zpgx8',
                    'mute': 1,
                    'playsinline': 1
                },
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady
                }
            });
        }

        // 3. Function to play video when player is ready
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        // 4. Ensure autoplay on iOS devices
        function isIOS() {
            return /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
        }

        if (isIOS()) {
            document.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
                player.mute();
                player.playVideo();
            });
        }
 .bg-video-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .bg-video-wrapper iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
   <div class="bg-video-wrapper">
        <iframe
            id="video-iframe"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t-ZNZYCB39s?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&mute=1&playsinline=1&background=1"
            frameborder="0"
            webkitallowfullscreen
            mozallowfullscreen
            allowfullscreen
            playsinline
            allow="autoplay; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture">
        </iframe>



